# Difference Between LASSO and $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Minimization Problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\Phi \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$. Let $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$, where $\mathbf{y} = \Phi \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ is additive white Gaussian noise.

The LASSO problem can be written as:

\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{x}} || \mathbf{y} - \Phi \mathbf{x} ||_2^2 + \lambda ||\mathbf{x}||_1 \quad \mbox{subject to} \quad \lambda > 0.
\end{align}

The $\ell_1$-norm minimization problem can be written as:
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{x}} || \mathbf{y} - \Phi \mathbf{x} ||_2^2  \quad \mbox{subject to} \quad ||\mathbf{x}||_1 \le \tau.
\end{align}

Are the solutions for the above two convex optimizaton problems the same? If yes, under what conditions are they same.

Comment: A Lagrange multiplier theorem tells us that for your second problem, there exists a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda \geq 0$ such that a minimizer for the constrained problem is also a minimizer for the unconstrained problem of minimizing $\| y - \Phi x \|_2^2 + \lambda (\| x \|_1 - \tau)$, or equivalently minimizing $\| y - \Phi x \|_2^2  + \lambda \| x \|_1$. The great thing about Lagrange multipliers is that they allow us to replace constraints (which seem difficult to handle) with penalty terms in the objective function. This allows us to just solve an unconstrained problem.

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54853.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The solution for both of the problems are the same. Following is a more general proof:
Let $f$ and $g$ be convex functions,
$$\
w_1^*= arg\underset{x}min \ f(x)+\lambda g(x) \quad \mbox{subject to} \quad \lambda > 0
$$
$$\
w_2^*= arg\underset{x}min \ f(x) \quad \mbox{subject to } \ g(x) \leq \tau
$$
Writing Lagrangian for the second problem,
$$\
\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = f(x)+\lambda_L\left(g(x) - \tau \right) \ \text{where } \lambda_L \text{ is the multiplier}
$$
From FONC for the second problem,
$$\
\nabla \mathcal{L}(w_2^*, \lambda^*) = \nabla f(w_2^*) +\lambda^*\left(\nabla g(w_2^*)\right) = 0 \ \text{where } \lambda^* = 0 \text{ if } g(w_2^*) < \tau
$$
For the first problem FONC gives,
$$\
\nabla f(w_1^*)+\lambda\left(\nabla g(w_1^*) \right)=0
$$
Since $f$ and $g$ are convex, we can conclude that both solutions are the same for
$$\
\tau=g(w_1^*) \text{ and corresponding multiplier } \lambda^*=\lambda
$$